# Copy file to RHV vms using RHV rest api

Tags: rest, virtual-machine

I need to copy certain files to vms hosting in the RHV server.

I prefer to use the RHV rest API but open for any other way as well.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy answer would be `scp`. Is there a reason why you cannot scp a file from the host to the VM? What is the VM's OS?